# How to find out which are the users who have used ( TS'ed) into our server in the last 3 month

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have joined a new team and we provide VM to other department of the my Company . Now we have created many VM and assigned to different department . At this point I want to know which are the servers which are actively used ( meaning someone has TS'ed into that server in the last 2 weeks ) . I have no idea how we can do this . Any help is truly appreciated.

We are running windows Server 2008 R2 Mostly .

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to query the event log with Powershell to get what you're after. Here's a one-liner to get you started:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 | ? {$_.TimeGenerated -gt '2015-04-14'}
```

You should be able to extend that to filter down to actual real users rather than automated tasks, services, etc.